# How to install gdk-3.0 on CentOS

Tags: centos

I'm trying to compile an application on CentOS. Compilation fail with following error :

```
  --- stderr
  `"pkg-config" "--libs" "--cflags" "gdk-3.0" "gdk-3.0 >= 3.18"` did not exit successfully: exit status: 1
  error: could not find system library 'gdk-3.0' required by the 'gdk-sys' crate

  --- stderr
  Package gdk-3.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
  Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gdk-3.0.pc'
  to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
  No package 'gdk-3.0' found
```

But I don't found any package with this name for CentOS (ex: https://pkgs.org/search/?q=gtk)

How to install it on CentOS ?

Answer (score 0):

As package name don't indicate it, gdk-3 can be installed with package `webkitgtk3-devel`.